# What finite non-abelian group is generated by $\operatorname{diag}(1,w,w^2,\ldots,w^{N-1})$ (with $w=e^{2\pi i/N}$) and a cyclic permutation matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

> What is the finite nonabelian group? generated by the following elements and satifies the rules:
>
> 1. $$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
>    1&0&0&\cdots&0\\
>    0&\omega&0&\cdots&0\\
>    0&0&\omega^2&\cdots &0\\
>    \vdots&\vdots&\vdots& &\vdots\\
>    0&0&0&\cdots&\omega^{N-1}
>    \end{array}\right)$$ where $\omega^{N}=1$ and $\omega = e^{2\pi i/N}$.
> 2. $$B=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
>    0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
>    0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
>     \vdots&\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
>    0&0&0&\cdots&1\\
>    1&0&0&\cdots&0
>    \end{array}\right)$$
> 3. $$AB=\omega \;BA$$ (or $AB=\omega^{-1} \;BA$)

It looks like this nonabelian group has an order $N^3$ at least. Because
$$
A^N=B^N=\omega^N=1,
$$
and all elements of these are distinct.

When $N=2$, the answer of this  nonabelian group seems to be a quaternion group of order $2^3=8$.

Comment: If you're defining $\omega$ to be a root of unity, isn't condition (3) redundant? Also, (2) isn't really a condition; it's just the definition of $B$. Also, where does this question come from? What's the context of this exercise?

Comment: It is just something I read from a paper. It is not homework.

Comment: They did not discuss the group structure - I wonder what it is? Shall be $\mathbb{Z}_N^2$-extension over $\mathbb{Z}_N$; or the other way around

Comment: Compare to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p).

Comment: When $N=2$ surely it's the dihedral group or order $8$.

Comment: For N=3, the Nonion group was discovered in [1884 by J J Sylvester](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/AAS8085.0004.001/165?cite1=Sylvester;cite1restrict=author;rgn=full+text;view=pdf), along with the generalization to the [clock and shift matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) you are looking at.

Answer (score 4):

The group $G = \langle A,B \rangle$ generated by $A$ and $B$ has order $N^3$ for all $N>1$.

There are $N$ conjugates $A_i = A^{B^i}$ $(0 \le i < N)$ of $A$ under powers of $B$, but $A_iA_{i-1}^{-1} = \omega I_n$, so the $A_i$ generate the group $N = \langle A,\omega I_n \rangle$, which has order $N^2$. Then $N \lhd G$ and $G/N$ is generated by the image $BN$ of $B$ and is cyclic of order $N$.

This is a nilpotent group of class $2$ with $Z(G) = [G,G] = \langle \omega I_n \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks! +1, Is there a name of this group?

Comment: @annie   Heisenberg group modulo N no good?

Comment: @CosmasZachos  Yes, that's right! Or the Heisenberg group over the ring ${\mathbb Z}/N{\mathbb Z}$.